# whats the best way to DRY private methods? Or does that defeat the purpose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have several private methods that I use in authentication of all pages in my app.  The whole idea of a private method is to not let it be called by other classes therefore centralizing seems to defeat the purpose. Yet as I get more used to "the ruby way" repeating myself is becoming more annoying.

Is there a way to do achieve DRY code without violating method privacy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it protected in your ApplicationController, or any other "base" controller you are using that all of your authenticated controllers extend.

Comment: Ah right...in Ruby child classes can access parent classes private parts (haha-that's funny). Thanks!